# API security questions in Django & React - Can Django validate if the userid in API == userid in Token?

Tags: django, authentication, security, django-rest-framework, react-typescript

In Django's views.py I have the following code:

```
class MutatieView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
# authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
serializer_class = MutatieSerializer
queryset = Mutatie.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    user_mutatie = Mutatie.objects.filter(userid=self.kwargs['userid'])
    return user_mutatie
```

In React a GET request is sent with the correct token in the header. But I commented out the original line (see below) and requested userid=1 instead of the userid as a variable of the current user which is 2.

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
reducerPath: "api",
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const access = (getState() as RootState).auth.access
        if (access) {
          headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${access}`);
        }
        return headers
      },
}),
tagTypes: ['MyMutatie',],
endpoints: (builder) => ({   
    ...
    myMutatieList: builder.query<IMutatie[], number>({
        query: (userid:number) => ({
            url: `mutaties/1/`,
            // url: `mutaties/${userid}/`,
        }),
    providesTags: ['MyMutatie']
    }),
    ...
}),
```

});

Now I get user1's data as user2, which is a problem.

Django should be able to see in the token that the correct userid=2 and not 1. **How to achieve such a validation?**

Is the developer the only one to manipulate api calls like in the code above or are there other ways? In postman, but django only allows APIs from the given domain? Can that also be faked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to send the userid as URL parameter, the Django authentication middleware will resolve that for you. Use:

```
user_mutatie = Mutatie.objects.filter(userid=self.request.user.id)
```

For `django only allows APIs from the given domain`, you can add the domain in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Comment: Last question: Could the API that React sends also be corrupted in someway? For example in a postman with replicating the request and even the CORS-origin? I guess the token (which is a long hash) can solve this issue because they cannot be cracked, right?

Comment: Haven't seen any such issues till now.